# Does an issue of bonus shares improve shareholder value?

Tags: investing, bonds

What I know is that, a splitting of shares doesn't improve shareholder value. It merely increase the number of shares. Hence, a splitting of stock shares improves market liquidity.

But what about bonus issue of stock?  For example: for every 5 shares you own, you are granted an additional share.

Comment: Are you asking about companies issuing bonuses to employees as stock options?

Comment: no. is not to employees as stock options. is to public as well, like saying, for every 5 shares you own, you are entitled for 1 free share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like "bonus shares" are the same as a stock dividend. Stock dividends are equivalent to a stock split except for accounting treatment (good explanation here: http://www.accountingcoach.com/online-accounting-course/17Xpg05.html).

As an investor, the only likely effect of a stock dividend is to make it more complex to keep track of cost basis and do your taxes. There's no
economic effect, it's just rearranging accounting numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This **IS** a stock split.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_split

> Ratios of 2-for-1, 3-for-1, and 3-for-2 splits are the most common, but any ratio is possible. Splits of 4-for-3, 5-for-2, and 5-for-4 are used, though less frequently. Investors will sometimes receive cash payments in lieu of fractional shares.

Comment: Stock dividends do have a slightly different accounting treatment, but yeah, they are the same as splits for practical purposes.

Comment: @Havoc I didn't fully read your answer first -- which is probably more relevant.

Answer (score -1):

The bonus share also improves the liquidity however there is some difference in treatment.

Lets say a company has 100 shares, of $10 ea. The total capital of the compnay is 100*10 = 1000.
Assuming the company is doing well, its share is now available in the market for $100 ea.
Now lets say the company has made a profit of $1000 and this also gets factored into the price of $100. Lets say the company decides to keep this $1000 kept as Cash Reserve and is not distributed as dividends.

In a share split say (1:1), the book value of each share is now reduced to $5, the number of shares increase to 200. The share capital stays at 200*5 = 1000. The market value of shares come down to $50 ea.

In a Bonus share issue say (1:1), the funds $1000 are moved from Cash Reserve and transferred to share capital. The book value of each share will remain same as $10, the number of shares increase to 200. The share capital increases to 200*10 = 2000. The market value of shares come down to $50 ea.

So essentially from a liquidity point of view both give the same benefit. As to why some companies issue bonus and not a split, this is because of multiple reasons. A split beyond a point cannot be done, ie $10 can be split to $1 ea but it doesn't look good to make it $0.50. The other reason is there is adequate cash reserve and you want to convert this into share holders capital. Having a larger share holders capital improves some of the health ratios for the compnay. At times bouns is used to play upon that one is getting something free.

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote?

Comment: I was not the downvote, but I'd suggest your explanation was too convoluted. The answer below was to the point.